# What does the authority section mean in dig results?

Tags: dns, dig

Yesterday I changed my domain's name server from cloudflare to dnspod. And I used dig to test it. But the ANSWER SECTION is always the old name servers.

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
amazingjxq.com.         21336   IN      NS      kim.ns.cloudflare.com.
amazingjxq.com.         21336   IN      NS      brad.ns.cloudflare.com.
```

Is the ANSWER SECTION stand for name servers? If so why is it not changed?

Comment: Serverfault.com would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes can we get this moved there? Thanks!

Comment: why off-topic? the "scope defined by the community" includes "software tools commonly used by programmers". I strongly oppose the decision to close.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The [Authority section indicates the server(s) that are the ultimate authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Authoritative_name_server) for answering DNS queries about that domain.

The reason for this section is that you can query any* DNS server(s) to answer a query for you. That server may choose though to answer the query from a cache. However, if you want to ensure you get an authoritative response ("from the horses mouth" so to speak) - you should ask the server(s) in the authority section.

(* = Any server which will accept your query, that is.)

Answer (score 9):

Those are cached records coming from the old servers.  Cloudflare has 1-day TTLs on the NS records, so that indicates that your resolver cached them about 18 hours ago, and they should go away in 6 hours.